# UILabel.text is overlapping on change

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uilabel

I have a simple `UIViewController` with `UILabel` and `UIButton`:

```
class MyScreen: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        let values = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"]
        var index = 0
        let label = UILabel(frame: .init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        label.textColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(label)
        let button = UIButton(frame: .init(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Tap", for: .normal)
        button.addAction(.init(handler: { _ in
            label.text = values[index]
            label.backgroundColor = (index % 2 == 0 ? nil : .red)
            index = (index + 1) % values.count
        }), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

As you can see I just change `label.text` and `label.backgroundColor` on tap. However, the text is overlapping. And `label.backgroundColor` is always `.red`.
[image: iPhone Simulator]

Is it an iOS bug? Or how can I change `UILabel.text` without overlapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue replace `label.backgroundColor = (index % 2 == 0 ? nil : .red)` with `label.backgroundColor = (index % 2 == 0 ? .clear : .red)`. You should not use `nil` for `UILabel.backgroundColor`.

Comment: From the documentation for `UIView.backgroundColor`: *"The default value is nil, which results in a transparent background color."*. But it does seem to cause an issue for a label.

Comment: @HangarRash I improved the example in my question, now I need to change `.backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make Label background color clear, so set to `.clear` or don't set background is well.

UIKit seems to change some value of views when drawing. If the label has no color (no something to fill contents), can set `isOpaque = false` to try.

Answer (score -1):

I'm able to reproduce your text overlapping issue and background mismatch while UILabel background color is resetted to nil:
`label.backgroundColor = (index % 2 == 0 ? nil : .red)`

As mentioned in other comments you should set it to `.clear` or `.black` instead of nil, it definitely fix the overlapping issue and the background is swapping correctly on my side.
Still strange that this issue exists, might that be a kind of fallback of the UILabel that is not expecting a nil. (debugging shows nothing strange tho and there are other issues on Slack talking about strange behaviours with `nil` as background, UILabel default value should probably be `.clear` in source code).